# Split Date Field In MySQL To Use YEAR and MONTH in WHERE Part of Query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that has a field called CREATED_DATE.  This pulls the date field from the database:

```
2015-05-11 12:23:58
```

However I need to split this date in the query itself as I need to use the year and the month in the where part of the query so for example:

```
SELECT CREATED_DATE FROM b_created_table WHERE YEAR = '2015' AND MONTH = '05'
```

What would I use to split it to get the two parts I need.  I would then us these parts AS YEAR and AS MONTH so that I could use them in the WHERE section of the query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your specific question is:

```
SELECT CREATED_DATE
FROM b_created_table
WHERE YEAR(CREATED_DATE) = 2015 AND MONTH(CREATED_DATE) = 05;
```

In general, though, you want to avoid functions on columns that might be indexed -- and `CREATED_DATE` might be indexed.  Functions prevent the index from being used.  You have several options, but here is an example of how to avoid this:

```
WHERE CREATED_DATE >= DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', '2015', '05', '01')) AND
      CREATED_DATE < DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', '2015', '05', '01')) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off not fiddling with field values in WHERE's (and JOIN conditions) if you can avoid it:

```
SELECT CREATED_DATE 
FROM b_created_table 
WHERE CREATED_DATE >= '2015-[TARGETMONTH]-01 00:00:00'
   AND CREATED_DATE < '2015-[TARGETMONTH]-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
;
```

But if you insist, MySQL has [YEAR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) functions.

...*2nd result found by googling "mysql year".*